# JavaScript Regex Producing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax-error

I have this in my JavaScript,

```
alert(words.match(\b.(\w*)\b));
```

, where `words` is a string previously defined. But, the regex (`\b.(\w*)\b`) is producing a console error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I think it's the backslashes, but no matter what I do, I still get the problem. I have thoroughly researched this problem on Stackoverflow and Google, but none of the results either works or meets my situation.

Here is the regex I am using: http://regexr.com?36u4v. Any held would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why has my question been voted down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes down to "Is `\b.(\w*)\b` *RegExp* ?" Well, kind of, but you haven't **told** the interpreter that. It is not a *RegExp literal* in *JavaScript*. You need to either pass it as a *String* into the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor, or use literal notation, which begins and ends with `/`

```
/\b.(\w*)\b/
```

As for your error, the interpreter reaches the `\` first and does not know what this means, so it tells you that the token (`\`) was unexpected, so is "illegal" where you used it.

---

For multiple matches, you'll need to set the `g`lobal flag, for example, to find "foo" multiple times

```
/foo/g
```

---

> does this regex work well for selecting all words, excluding spaces and punctuation (other than underscores and hyphens)

`\w` is [**shorthand**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for the class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so you're not matching hyphens at the moment. Your `.` will also match most characters including spaces and punctuation. You can swap the `*` (zero or more) for a `+` (one or more) so you don't need the `.`. Therefore the following may be more suitable for your needs

```
/\b([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\b/g
```

Comment: Okay, well that fixes the problem, with a nice explanation. But, now I am faced with another. This regex was supposed to select all words, excluding spaces and punctuation (other than underscores and hyphens), but now it's not doing that. On regexr, it was showing it working well, but now it's not.

Comment: Remember that `.` will match almost anything and that if you want multiple finds, you'll need to set the `g`lobal flag.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to fix it.

Comment: It won't let me accept answer yet. By the way, does this regex work well for selecting all words, excluding spaces and punctuation (other than underscores and hyphens), or is there a better way?

Comment: @Mr.Shtuffs please see edit where I explain why, too

Comment: The second suggestion (`/\b([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\b/g`) produces the same error, except the `;` at the end of the line, after the regex, is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put your regex literal into slashes:

```
alert(words.match(/\b.(\w*)\b/));
```